# Tkinter callback function causing ValueError

Tags: python, callback, tkinter

I am having problem with the callback function of the tkinter trace method. I would like to have 2 entries and the value of each entry depends on the value of another. So if I change the value of one, the value of the other is changed. This is some simple code doing this:

```
from tkinter import *

class main():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.a = DoubleVar(value=2.0)
        self.b = DoubleVar()
        self.b.trace("w",self.calc_c)
        self.c = DoubleVar()
        self.c.trace("w",self.calc_b)

        Entry(master,textvariable=self.b).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Entry(master,textvariable=self.c).grid(row=0,column=1)

    def calc_b(self,name,index,mode):
        self.b.set(self.c.get()/self.a.get())

    def calc_c(self,name,index,mode):
        self.c.set(self.b.get()*self.a.get())


root = Tk()

prog = main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The program is actually working, returning the right values, but also an error is produced:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/anze/foo.py", line 22, in calc_c
    self.c.set(self.b.get()*self.a.get())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 332, in get
    return getdouble(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Can someone please explain the meaning of this error?

Thank you!

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. Do you not understand what "could not convert string to float" means, or do you need some other type of help?

Comment: I don't understand which string is being converted to float. As far as I know, all variables are floats, but obviously this is not the case, so I'm confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the widget is an Entry, which takes a string as input, and your value is a DoubleVar, but you have no validation in place to prevent the user entering an invalid value.

Your code works as long as the input value is a float. When you call `get()` in `calc_c` and `calc_b` after an invalid value was entered, tkinter tries to convert the string in the Entry into a float, fails and throws a ValueError exception.

You can catch the exception with a try-except block. In the `try` block you put the code that might raise an exception. The `except` block defines what happens when an exception is caught. You can also have an `else` block that defines what happens when no exception is caught.

Here's a simple example (with no else block) for calc_c that restores the previous value (calc_b would need to be modified in a similar way):

```
def calc_c(self,name,index,mode):
    try:
        self.c.set(self.b.get()*self.a.get())
    except ValueError:
        # here you can either complain to the user (message-box...) 
        # or just restore the last value using the other entry like so:
        self.b.set(self.c.get()/self.a.get())
```

Comment: But I am getting this error even if the entry is a valid number, not some invalid string. In that case I shouldn't be getting the error, should I?

Comment: Are you selecting the whole number and trying to type over it? I just tried it and I get the same message as you. You can't see the string in the message because it's an empty string. (For this, the code I posted as an example will prevent it crashing but it won't give the correct behaviour.)

Comment: What I mean is: When you type over the old number, what really happens is that the Entry box gets emptied first (so it contains an empty string) then its content is replaced with the character(s) you typed in. But it never gets to that point because the exception kicks in as soon as the Entry box is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are binding self.c to an Entry widget:

```
Entry(master,textvariable=self.c).grid(row=0,column=1)
```

But, the textvariable should be set to a `Tkinter.StringVar`. How about creating a new variable to hold the Entry's string value and then convert in your calc method:

```
from tkinter import *

class main():

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.a = DoubleVar(value=2.0)
        self.b = DoubleVar()
        self.b.trace("w",self.calc_c)
        self.c = DoubleVar()
        self.c_str = StringVar()
        self.c.trace("w",self.calc_b)

        Entry(master,textvariable=self.b).grid(row=0,column=0)
        Entry(master,textvariable=self.c_str).grid(row=0,column=1)

    def calc_b(self,name,index,mode):
        self.c.set(float(self.c_str.get()))
        self.b.set(self.c.get()/self.a.get())

    def calc_c(self,name,index,mode):
        self.c.set(self.b.get()*self.a.get())


root = Tk()

prog = main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Note you'll probably want to do the same for the other Entry.

Comment: I agree, textvariable of the Entry widget should be a string. Also in that case, I think this should work:
`Entry(master,textvariable=str(self.b)).grid(row=0,column=0)        Entry(master,textvariable=str(self.c)).grid(row=0,column=1)`
but it doesn't. I also tried your code and I didn't get the change in the first entry when changing the second.

Comment: Not a string, a Tkinter.StringVar. so using str() will not work. Changing the entries' values is really a separate question from the ValueError, and I'm assuming you'll just need to update calc_c to behave similarly to calc_b

Comment: @user2923638 how are you getting along? If this answer helped you, kindly click the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error using `Tk.scale(... resolution=0.1, ...)`.
When there was `matplotlib` used in the same script, the decimal number  from scale was written with `,` instead of `.` and caused an error in `getdouble()`.

I found a workaround by changing the regional settings of the os(kubuntu14.04) from German to US with `.` as default decimal seperator.

It not satisfying solution but may help to find the problem.